# Unable to make the chrome extension work in the background when the extension is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The setInterval script works when the popup is open. But when the extension is closed, the script doesn't run in the background. Here is the code:

Manifest.json:

```
"browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "iho.png",
   "default_popup": "index.html"
 },
"permissions": [
  "activeTab", "<all_urls>"
 ],
"background": {
   "scripts": [
      "background.js"
   ]
 },
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["bundle.js"]
  }
 ]
```

hello.js

```
var MainApp = React.createClass({
  submitForm: function (e){
    event.preventDefault();

    function myCallback(){
      alert("hi there")
    }

    window.setInterval(myCallback, 8000);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.submitForm}> click me! </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "bundle.js"});
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Why are you showing *hello.js* when it is not referenced anywhere? Where are *bundle.js*, and *index.html*? What is your *exact* problem? You appear to be using React, but don't load it. Why are you injecting *bundle.js* as a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` *and* using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` to also inject it.?

Comment: 1. Toolbar popup environment is destroyed when closed. 2. browserAction.onClicked won't work when popup html file is specified. 3. Make sure to read the extensions overview, especially the architecture article.